# What is the chance of transactions being processed in different order that they are broadcast

Tags: transaction-verification

Given I want to transfer bitcoin from A to B, and then from B to C. I broadcast two transactions to the network (with the same transaction fee), in order: A to B and then B to C. Is there any chance that the second transaction gets processed before the first (and thus rendered invalid because the bitcoin has not yet arrived in B)?

Answer (score 5):

The clients receiving B->C first will keep it in the memory (transaction pool) and denote is as an orphaned transaction, until they find A->B. So unless network propagation is terribly slow: no, it will not be rendered invalid.

Comment: Thanks. It makes easy for me to broadcast multiple transactions to the network then :)

Comment: I relay my transaction through webbtc.com and I can see that if the transaction is valid, then the network accept it. If it depend on unconfirmed transaction, then the network simply discarded it.